# how to retrieve the data from the database according to check box selected?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

[image]

I am having collection of check boxes i want to select the values according to the check box selected please help me

```
API:Characteristics__c

    public void Submit() {

        Selection = new List<string>();
        if(Good_with_Cats == true) Selection.add('Good_with_Cats');
        if(HighNeed == true) Selection.add('High Need');
        if(Non_shedder == true) Selection.add('Non-shedder');
        if(kid_friendly == true) Selection.add('Kid Friendly');
        if(Predatory_Tendencies == true) Selection.add('Predatory Tendencies');

    }

    <apex:pageBlock title="Characteristics Information" >
                 Goods with Cats<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Good_with_Cats}"/> 
                 High Need<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!HighNeed}"/>
                <br/>
                 Non-shedder&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Non_shedder}"/>                               
                 Kid Friendly<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!kid_friendly}"/>
                <br/>
                 Predatory Tendencies<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Predatory_Tendencies}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!Submit}"/>  
                <br/>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing and how is your vf page?

Comment: i have attached the snap of the ui. if i select a checkbox and hit the search button means values must search display the record in the apex:pageBlockTable.

Comment: anyone there please help me

Comment: @muralimano. If you tell us what you've tried so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you.  Posting requests to write code for you generally get closed.

Comment: Add an outputText in vf. Assign it a text variable in the class. In submit button code, put the selection value to the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have getter setter declared for each checkbox like

```
public boolean Good_with_Cats {get;set;}

public boolean HighNeed {get;set;}
```

If the value is selected, it will become true which we can check in our controller like:-

```
if ( Good_with_Cats == true ){

 // do something

}
if ( HighNeed == true ){

}
```

Comment: i want display the value in the table